# ASP.NET Core MVC - Send data to model inside another model with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my first time asking here. I'm just wondering if there's a way to send a model data inside another model from ajax to controller.

Here's my model:

```
public class mfItems
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Item ID")]
    public string ItemID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Model Description")]
    public string ItemModelDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public decimal ItemUnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And my other model:

```
public class trnPurchaseOrderLists
{
    public mfItems Items { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my ajax and in this ajax I tried to log the `data.items.itemid` but this isn't sending an id but when I remove the `console.log(data.items.itemid)` and to the controller `hey.Items.ItemID = id` another data which is quantity is working very well.

```
function change_quantity(id) {
    var value = $('#' + id).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("ChangeQuantity")",
        data: { id: id, value: value },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.items.itemid);
            console.log(data.quantity);
        }
    });
}
```

Lastly here's my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public trnPurchaseOrderLists ChangeQuantity(string id,decimal value)
{
     trnPurchaseOrderLists hey = new trnPurchaseOrderLists();
     hey.Items.ItemID = id;
     hey.Quantity = value;
     return hey;
}
```

Where am I wrong? please help thanks. If you find my English is very confusing I apologize. I'm really not good at English. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @JeffreyEstrera welcome to StackOverflow. `hey.Items` is a `mfItems` instance. To access `hey.Items.ItemID`, you need instantiate `hey.Items` in your API first. `hey.Items = new mfItems();`. Then you are only able to assign `hey.Items.ItemID = id;`.

Comment: Hello and thank you. Actually i'm not using an API. Is there anyway to achieve it without using an API? Sorry I'm completely newbie on MVC Core

Comment: @JeffreyEstera, oops, the declaration `hey.Items = new mfItems();` should be in your Controller for this `ChangeQuantity` method, not API. Sorry for the wrong mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not getting anymore error. However there's still a problem. It is my ID is undefined. But by looking at my input

<input id="@item.Items.ItemID" class="form-control" value="@item.Quantity" oninput="return change_quantity('@item.Items.ItemID')"/> i think there's nothing wrong with this ? right? coz i already sent the id through function of an input. How come is this still undefined:?

Comment: Hi @Jeffrey, I think you need to check your GET method (that bind data to view), it has returned the value for `@item.Items.ItemID` to your view or not. And next to check that your HTML input element `id` and `change_quantity` method contains value or not.

Feel free to create another post to mention the issue you faced, and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for your answer sir. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1)Initialize items

```
[HttpPost]
public trnPurchaseOrderLists ChangeQuantity(string id,decimal value)
{
     trnPurchaseOrderLists hey = new trnPurchaseOrderLists();
     hey.Items = new mfItems();//Initialize items here
     hey.Items.ItemID = id;
     hey.Quantity = value;
     return hey;
}
```

2)Change itemid to itemId;

```
function change_quantity(id) {
    var value = $('#' + id).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("ChangeQuantity")",
        data: { id: id, value: value },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.items.itemId);//changed itemid to itemId;
            console.log(data.quantity);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I already did this sir. But according to console my id is undefined. How would I fix this? i tried to put id to window alert and it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ViewModel class

```
public class ViewModel
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public decimal Value {get; set;}
}
```

fix action

```
public IActionResult ChangeQuantity(ViewModel viewModel)
{
  var id=viewModel.Id;
  var value=viewModel.Value
.....
return Ok(hey);
}
```

and fix ajax

```
function change_quantity(id) {
    var value = $('#' + id).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ ..controller.../ChangeQuantity",
        data: { id: id, value: value },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.items.itemid);
            console.log(data.quantity);
        }
    });
}
```